# Reading all the file using Fread c

Tags: c, import, fread

1. I need to read a full binary file to a buffer in my program , when I do fread it isn't working :( , how can I import all the file with all the binary chars?
2. I want to read a string from binary file but again it isn't reading all the string I want.

   The File:

   ```
   [®ןƒפ׃mױ<¬‰¯W
   Aזם­ׁׂ0]:w‚A‎‏־}˜-]—F7§c.®4¡­9׳vhֳ7 ןעGOֱ¸^£­}    ֻמךY&@ל÷ף יˆ»¼hYc,אxFxְ ׃ ­/=%y׳י×®m«₪"³P   UײIE,Lעׂ“ ֽ₪4Cִֺ׀¯jך_GX&j’=Xr׀¶Fש`<ֳ¿6ֿנסv״›^smNYֵ›@ORת»ty5¼©`‎f¾| סה/:‹¹s׀ןZ½q\¢ַסס,Kˆֿ<»¦ֱWI–Dµ@₪ֲֻ[!Hoנ>¥
   „­¢דת\‰jֶק³lב’’`…־°ׂ-ץַˆ/7¬!8ם‰66]ן›Rװֶ~‰50¶
   %ֺץYָעך”a¢s˜–›*ק·צkWnTPxC¬#«ץZב₪ָ€זo[ֻכֻּ00}¨לgֶˆVַ₪°p§צ‘שw¾ו½״Y.״tPן  QNּoי±¯fGָֹ†]»)LY2&joדעB ¶.ׂ
   8+U£־I;ײsE!מ¼כ“¹׳־הֶמ½]’²­‚iy?r·*ח׳גֺפ
   ```

The Code :

```c
void main()
{
    int size;
    FILE * file1;
    file=fopen("file","rb");
    char * buff;
    fseek(file,0,seek_end);// calculating the length of the file
    size=ftell(file)+1;
    fseek(file,0,seek_set);
    buff=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*size));
    fread(buff,1,size,file);// this line isn't working,I have a file with
                          // a size of 495 but it's reads only 5 elements.
    free(buff);
}
```

Comment: Fyi, you know you're telling `fread` to read one more byte than the file size, right? And since you never check the result of `fread` (or any of your other library call results on that note), how *exactly* are you determining how many bytes have actually been read? Finally, `file1` is declared, but `file` is used. How about posting the *real* code.

Comment: And don't cast the return value of `malloc()`. One important thing, how do you know how many elements it's reading if you are not checking that? it would be `size - 1`, so `int count = fread(buff, 1, size, file);` then `count` is `size -1`.

Comment: I looked on the string in Visual Studio and the size of the string was wrong , but thank you both , I will check if its works.

Comment: The number of the chars is right , thank you . but why the chars are not same? the number of read chars is 494 but I see only 135 .

Comment: @MherTolpin 'cos your debugger stops at null.